# Let $W$ be a square matrix. If $W+W'$ is positive definite, what one can say about $W$?

Tags: linear-algebra, positive-definite

Let $W$ be a square matrix. If $W+W'$ is positive definite, what one can say about $W$?

Can you say that $W$ is invertible?

Can you say that $W$ is positive or negative definite?

Notation:  $'$  means tranpose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: Assuming $W$ is symmetric. Suppose $W+W^T$ is positive definite and let $v$ be an eigenvector of $W$ with corresponding eigenvalue $\lambda$, then we see that
\begin{align}
2\lambda || v||^2=v^T(W+W^T)v > 0
\end{align}
which means $\lambda > 0$. Thus, if $W+W^T$ is positive definite, then $W$ and, of course, $W^T$, will also be positive definite (Note: $W$ is invertible since $\lambda>0$).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I understood the part that $W$ is invertible. However, I didnt understand what did you mean by ''$W$ **or** $W^T$ will also be positive definite.'' If $W$ is positive definite, then $W$ is symmetric, then $W^T=W$, which means that $W$ **and** $W^T$ are positive definite.

Comment: It should be an "and".

Comment: Ok, one last thing. It's not sufficient to show that if all eigenvalues of $W$ are positive, then $W$ is positive definite, because $W$ must be symmetric in the first place. And I dont know if $W$ is guaranteed symmetric in this case. Do you?

Comment: $W$ is not guaranteed symmetric. Take the example $W=\begin{bmatrix}0.9649&0.9706\\0.1576&0.9572\end{bmatrix} $. You can see that $W'+W$ is positive definite, but $W$ isnt since $W$ is not symmetric ( it has all eigenvalues  greater than zero, though). Anyway, I'm satisfied now.

Answer (score 1):

They may even fail to be positive or negative *semi*definite:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}2&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}2&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\1&1\end{bmatrix}
$$

**Edit:** after the question has been edited to mean something else. If $W$ is positive-definite, then $W'$ is also positive-definite (assuming we are talking real matrices), because $$x'W'x=(x'W'x)'=x'Wx>0,$$ and then $W+W'$ is positive definite since the sum of positive-definite is again positive-definite.

Comment: please read the question again, it was badly-written and caused confusion.

Comment: Ok. $\ \ \ \ \ $

Comment: You've inverted the roles of hypothesis and thesis here. If $W+W'$ is positive definite what can I say about $W$? The question is not assuming anything about $W$ to conclude a thesis about $W+W'$

Comment: But, nevermind. @Jacky Chong already answered.

Answer (score 1):

Let $W$ be the  3x3 matrix with ones on the diagonal and $0.1$ above the diagonal. Then, $W$ is not positive definite (or negative definite) since it isn't even symmetric. But, $W^T + W$ is positive definite.